# I want to avoid Out Of Memory Exception using best practice to load image bitmaps in android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, bitmapimage

I want to use steps depicted in tutorial "Loading large bitmaps effectively". But I am confused about how to determine appropriate height and width of image to be displayed in any device. In tutorial required height and width are hard coded. I want appropriate required height and width for any device dynamically. How to do it...

Thanks...

Steps In tutorial are as follows 
getting image height and width

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

calculating inSample size for decoding image bitmap

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    final int halfHeight = height / 2;
    final int halfWidth = width / 2;

    // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
    // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
    while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
            && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
        inSampleSize *= 2;
    }
}

return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: How are you defining your ImageView ?

Comment: I have used custom ImageView  <com.polites.android.GestureImageView
         android:id="@+id/image"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:src="@drawable/sample" />

Comment: How are you using it in your xml/java code? Do you have it's width/height set with dp units or WRAP_CONTENT/MATCH_PARENT?

Comment: I have set fill parent for both width and height

Comment: I have put this ImageView in relative layout which also has width and height match parent and I am inflating this layout in ImageAdapter using pageAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
final ImageView myImage = (ImageView) view
        .findViewById(R.id.test_image);
final ViewParent parent = myImage.getParent();

if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
    ((ViewGroup) parent).getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    ((ViewGroup) parent).getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                    int reqWidth = ((ViewGroup) parent).getWidth();
                    int reqHeight = ((ViewGroup) parent).getHeight();

                    // Load image...
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare the tag i.e

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

within your `<application>` tag in your manifest.

Example :-

```
<application 

    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:description="@string/app_description"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    >
```